# Is there a way to write a typeguard against a complex combinatory type that preserves previous type information?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeguards

Is there a way to write a TypeScript typeguard against a complex combinatory type (that uses many "and" and "or" statements) to test the existence of one of the "or" types?

For example:

```
interface Type1 { cat: string }
interface Type2 { dog: boolean }
interface Type3 { mouse: number }
interface Type4 { elephant: string | number }
type CombinatoryType = (Type1 & (Type2 | Type3)) | Type4;
```

If we have a typeguard to check the existence of Type2 and Type4 (called `hasType2` and `hasType4` respectively), calling them in the following order should produce the following results:

```
function doSomething(data: CombinatoryType) {
    if (hasType2(data)) {
        // 'data' is now of type: (Type1 & Type2) | Type4

        if (hasType4(data)) {
            // 'data' is now of type: Type1 & Type2 & Type4
       }
    }
}
```

And calling them in the opposite order should produce the following results:

```
function doSomething(data: CombinatoryType) {
    if (hasType4(data)) {
        // 'data' is now of type: (Type1 & (Type2 | Type3)) & Type4

        if (hasType2(data)) {
            // 'data' is now of type: Type1 & Type2 & Type4
       }
    }
}
```

Important to note:

- As demonstrated above, the typeguard should not lose previous type information (e.g. from previous type assertions made)
- The typeguard should also not use an explicit return type (e.g. `data is (Type1 & Type2) | Type4`) as the combinatory type could get very long. This also tricks VSCode's type inference into thinking the asserted value is exactly that type (although intellisense still works fine).

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct in your provide code, you want to create type guards for these `Type2` and `Type4` in the `CombinatoryType` type. Isn't it?

If so, here is an example I can provide:

```
function hasType2(data: CombinatoryType): data is (Type1 & Type2) | Type4 {
   return 'dog' in data;
}

function hasType4(data: CombinatoryType): data is (Type1 & (Type2 | Type3)) & Type4 {
   return 'elephant' in data;
}
```

In the above sample, we're using the `in` operator to check if the `dog` property exists in `data` for `hasType2`, and if the `elephant` property exists in `data` for `hasType4`.

The `in` operator is a type guard that checks if a property exists in an object.

The **data is (Type1 & Type2) | Type4** and **data is (Type1 & (Type2 | Type3)) & Type4** syntax is used to tell TypeScript that if the function returns `true`, then `data` is of the specified type.

Now, you can use these type guards in your `doSomething` function:

```
function doSomething(data: CombinatoryType) {
   if (hasType2(data)) {
       // 'data' is now of type: (Type1 & Type2) | Type4

       if (hasType4(data)) {
           // 'data' is now of type: Type1 & Type2 & Type4
       }
   }
}
```

In this function, if `hasType2(data)` returns `true`, then that `data` is of type **(Type1 & Type2) | Type4** within the first `if`. If `hasType4(data)` also returns `true` , then that `data` is of type **Type1 & Type2 & Type4** within the second `if`.

The same logic applies to the second `doSomething` function, where the type guards are called in the opposite order.

## Edit

I will provide this sample;

```
type Type1 = { /* ... */ };
type Type2 = { /* ... */ };
type Type3 = { /* ... */ };
type Type4 = { /* ... */ };

type CombinatoryType = Type1 & Type2 & Type3;

function hasType2(data: CombinatoryType): data is CombinatoryType & Type2 {
 // Check if 'data' has properties of Type2
 return (data as Type2) /* ... */ !== undefined;
}

function hasType4(data: CombinatoryType & Type2): data is CombinatoryType & Type2 & Type4 {
 // Check if 'data' has properties of Type4
 return (data as Type4) /* ... */ !== undefined;
}

function doSomething(data: CombinatoryType) {
  if (hasType2(data)) {
      // 'data' is now of type: (Type1 & Type2) | Type4

      if (hasType4(data)) {
          // 'data' is now of type: Type1 & Type2 & Type4
      }
  }
}
```

In the sample above, `hasType2` and `hasType4` functions, they check whether `data` has properties of `Type2` and `Type4` respectively, and if so, they narrow down the type of `data` to `CombinatoryType & Type2` and `CombinatoryType & Type2 & Type4` respectively. This allows you to preserve the previous type information of `data` and add new types to it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without explicit typing, as combinatory types can get quite long?
Something like `: data is CombinatoryType & Type4`?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question to account for my previous comment

Comment: Sorry if I was late. I edit the answer.